# How can i use SteamAPI with Django?

Tags: python, django, steam, steam-web-api

How can this be possible? I am trying to add steam authentication button in my website and get general information: username, steam id.

something like this as example:

`views.py`:

```
# Example
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http return HttpResponse

def index(response):
    ...
    return render('link.html', response) # link html contains <a> tag which should lead to steam authentication.
    ...

def afterauth(request):
    if auth = SteamAuth.wasSucessful:
        return HttpResponse("Username: " + SteamAuth.Username() + "SteamID: " + SteamAuth.ID())
```

I have gotten the API key, but i couldn't find any documentation regarding how to use it with Django.

Is there any way i can achieve this? Are there any tutorial's or documentation where i can use Steam API with Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`python-social-auth`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-social-auth/) package that has native support for both django and the steam API:

> #### Multiple frameworks are supported:
>
> - **Django**
> - Flask
> - Pyramid
> - Webpy
> - Tornado
>
> ---
>
> #### Auth providers
>
> - ...
> - Soundcloud OAuth2
> - Stackoverflow OAuth2
> - **Steam OpenId**
> - Stocktwits OAuth2
> - Strava OAuth2
> - Stripe OAuth2
> - ...

Comment: Thanks! is there any tutorial for this?

Comment: The [official documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a good start.

Comment: As for Dec 03 2016, this library is now deprecated, the codebase was split and migrated into the python-social-auth organization, where a more organized development process is expected to take place. https://github.com/python-social-auth

Answer (score 1):

For Python3 and Django 2.x, [django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) can be used. They support pretty much every provider available and I have used it multiple times for Steam authentication with very little effort